# Kotlin - How to get a property from an object in collection

Tags: kotlin

I have never worked before with Kotlin so I have a newbie question. I am working with an existing codebase, so I am wondering about a few things. I see that there is a function **getDepartmentById** which looks like this:

```
fun getDepartmentById(ctx: Ctx, params: JsonObject): Either<Failure, FlatResp> =
    getOneByIdFlattened(ctx, params.right(), getDepartmentByIdSql(ctx), flattenOne = flattenerToType(MainAccessType.DEPARTMENT))

fun getDepartmentById(ctx: Ctx, id: Long): Either<Failure, FlatResp> =
    getDepartmentById(ctx, jsonObject("id" to id))
```

Calling that function returns either Failure or FlatResp. From what I can see in the code **FlatResponse** is typealias for `Map<MainAccessType, Entities>`.

The function **getOneByIdFlattened** looks like this:

```
fun getOneByIdFlattened(ctx: Ctx,
                        params: Either<Long, JsonObject>,
                        statement: String,
                        rowConverter: (Row) -> Map<String, Any?> = ::mapFromDbNames,
                        grouper: (List<Map<String, Any?>>) -> List<Map<String, Any?>> = ::identity,
                        flattenOne: (List<Map<String, Any?>>) -> FlatResp
): Either<Failure, FlatResp> =
    either.eager {
      val id = when (params) {
        is Either.Left -> Either.Right(params.value)
        is Either.Right -> params.value.idL?.right()
            ?: Failure.JsonError(SErr(GlowErrs.MISSING_ID, "You must provide id")).left()
      }.bind()

      val dbDataList: List<Map<String, Any?>> = doQuery(ctx, statement, mapOf(
          "courierIds" to ctx.user.courierIds,
          "id" to id,
          "count" to 1,
          "offset" to 0,
          "departmentIds" to ctx.userDepartments,
          "customerIds" to ctx.user.customerIds
      ),
          rowConverter, false
      ).bind()
      val result = flattenOne(grouper(dbDataList))
      addUpdatedAtEpoch(result)
    }
```

I wonder how can I get from a FlatResp a property of an object, that looks like this:

[image]

So, for example if I want to get just **`name`** from this object what would be the best way to do this?
Also, I wonder why is this function returning a collection, and not just a single object when it should get a single row by id from DB?

This is the sql function:

```
private fun getDepartmentByIdSql(ctx: Ctx) =
    """select ${createSelectFields(departmentKeys)}
        from department dept
        where dept.id = :id
  ${
      when (ctx.user.role) {
        UserRoles.ADMIN -> ""
        else -> "and dept.id = any (:departmentIds) "
      }
    }"""
```

Comment: What are `Either`, `Failure` and `FlatResponse`? Are those from some external library or developed in-house?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar from what I can see FlatResponse is typealias for Map<MainAccessType, Entities>

Comment: what is `getOneByIdFlattened(ctx,...)`?

Comment: @anshsachdeva I have updated question with the getOneByIdFlattened function code

Answer (score 1):

So there are a lot of things wrong in the snippet provided. Given Snippets:

- 1

```
fun getDepartmentById(ctx: Ctx, params: JsonObject): Either<Failure, FlatResp> =
    getOneByIdFlattened(ctx, params.right(), getDepartmentByIdSql(ctx), flattenOne = flattenerToType(MainAccessType.DEPARTMENT))
```

- 2

```
fun getDepartmentById(ctx: Ctx, id: Long): Either<Failure, FlatResp> =
    getDepartmentById(ctx, jsonObject("id" to id))
```

- 3

```
private fun getDepartmentByIdSql(ctx: Ctx) =
    """select ${createSelectFields(departmentKeys)}
        from department dept
        where dept.id = :id
  ${
      when (ctx.user.role) {
        UserRoles.ADMIN -> ""
        else -> "and dept.id = any (:departmentIds) "
      }
    }"""
```

- 4

```
fun getOneByIdFlattened(ctx: Ctx,
                        params: Either<Long, JsonObject>,
                        statement: String,
                        rowConverter: (Row) -> Map<String, Any?> = ::mapFromDbNames,
                        grouper: (List<Map<String, Any?>>) -> List<Map<String, Any?>> = ::identity,
                        flattenOne: (List<Map<String, Any?>>) -> FlatResp
): Either<Failure, FlatResp> =
    either.eager {
      val id = when (params) {
        is Either.Left -> Either.Right(params.value)
        is Either.Right -> params.value.idL?.right()
            ?: Failure.JsonError(SErr(GlowErrs.MISSING_ID, "You must provide id")).left()
      }.bind()

      val dbDataList: List<Map<String, Any?>> = doQuery(ctx, statement, mapOf(
          "courierIds" to ctx.user.courierIds,
          "id" to id,
          "count" to 1,
          "offset" to 0,
          "departmentIds" to ctx.userDepartments,
          "customerIds" to ctx.user.customerIds
      ),
          rowConverter, false
      ).bind()
      val result = flattenOne(grouper(dbDataList))
      addUpdatedAtEpoch(result)
    }
```

Issues:

1. in snippet 2, `jsonObject` should be `JsonObject(..)`
2. I have no idea what the following lines do :

```
//snippet1:  
flattenOne = flattenerToType(MainAccessType.DEPARTMENT)) 


//snipper 4
either.eager {...block...}
addUpdatedAtEpoch(result)
doQuery(ctx, statement, mapOf(..)

//snippet3
UserRoles.ADMIN -> ""
"""select ${createSelectFields(departmentKeys)}
```

They are all probably some extension functions or util files made by your company or from some famous libraries like [anko](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko) or[splitties](https://github.com/LouisCAD/Splitties) . plus these are mixes with function calls of your own class, like `createSelectFields` or `ctx.user.courierIds`. also if i have to guess, then  this seems like an unusual way of performing some operation on an sql dB

based on just code completion by android studio, i have been able to figure out the classes as following:

```kotlin
class  Entities
typealias  FlatResp = Map<MainAccessType, Entities>

class Ctx
sealed class Either<A,B>(val a:A?, val b:B?){
    val value:A? = null

    class Left<A>(val aa:A):Either<A,A>(aa,aa)
    class Right<B>(val bv:B):Either<B,B>(bb,bb)
}
class Failure
class Row
class JsonObject(val pair:Pair<String,Long>):JSONObject(){
    fun right():Either<Long,JsonObject>{
    }
}
class jsonObject()
enum class MainAccessType{DEPARTMENT}

fun getDepartmentById(ctx: Ctx, params: JsonObject): Either<Failure, FlatResp> {
    return getOneByIdFlattened(
        ctx,
        params.right(),
        getDepartmentByIdSql(ctx),
        flattenOne = flattenerToType(MainAccessType.DEPARTMENT))
}

fun getDepartmentById(ctx: Ctx, id: Long): Either<Failure, FlatResp> {
    return getDepartmentById(ctx, JsonObject("id" to id))
}

fun getOneByIdFlattened(ctx: Ctx,
                        params: Either<Long, JsonObject>,
                        statement: String,
                        rowConverter: (Row) -> Map<String, Any?> = ::mapFromDbNames,
                        grouper: (List<Map<String, Any?>>) -> List<Map<String, Any?>> = ::identity,
                        flattenOne: (List<Map<String, Any?>>) -> FlatResp
): Either<Failure, FlatResp> {
    return either.eager {
        val id = when (params) {
            is Either.Left -> Either.Right(params.value)
            is Either.Right -> params.value.idL?.right()
                ?: Failure.JsonError(SErr(GlowErrs.MISSING_ID, "You must provide id")).left()
        }.bind()

        val dbDataList: List<Map<String, Any?>> = doQuery(ctx, statement, mapOf(
            "courierIds" to ctx.user.courierIds,
            "id" to id,
            "count" to 1,
            "offset" to 0,
            "departmentIds" to ctx.userDepartments,
            "customerIds" to ctx.user.customerIds
        ),
            rowConverter, false
        ).bind()
        val result = flattenOne(grouper(dbDataList))
        addUpdatedAtEpoch(result)
    }
}

private fun getDepartmentByIdSql(ctx: Ctx) =
    """select ${createSelectFields(departmentKeys)}
        from department dept
        where dept.id = :id
  ${
        when (ctx.user.role) {
            UserRoles.ADMIN -> ""
            else -> "and dept.id = any (:departmentIds) "
        }
    }"""

fun mapFromDbNames(row:Row): Map<String,Any?>{

}

fun identity(param : List<Map<String, Any?>>): List<Map<String, Any?>>{

}
```

This is still not correct and has a lots of red lines in it. but what you can do is keep this as a starter in a separate file, compare and fix the code accordingly and then maybe we can tell what would be a better way:

1. replace inline functions (`fun xyz(...) = someValue` ) to block functions. (alt+enter in windows, cmd+n in mac)
2. instead of typeAlias, use map directly
3. `::something` means a function is passed as parameter . its similar to how we pass runnables in java 8, but even more shorthand. you can do ctrl+click( for mac its cmd+click)  on that function  and goto that function to check what its params are, what its  return type are. do the same for various classes/ extension fucntions, variables too. **this will help the most**
4. instead of passing something into something which is being passed into another thing (like `val bot = Robot(Petrol("5Litres") )`  ) , split into different lines to make it understandable ( `val amount = "5litres"; val equipment = Petrol(amount) ; val bot = Robot(equipment)` )
5. try to not use 3rd party library/ replace with your own understandable code.
6. repeat steps 1-5

Hope this gives someplace to start. kotlin is a beautiful language but is also very easy to make unreadable.

Comment: I am mostly wondering what would be the best way of extracting a wanted property from an object within collection, like the one I posted an image in my question.

Comment: hmm, then in that case, the `result` object might have value for `name` and you can access it via `result["name"]

Answer (score 0):

#### Mapping `Map` values

> I wonder how can I get from a FlatResp a property of an object, that looks like this:
>
> [image]
>
> So, for example if I want to get just name from this object what would be the best way to do this?

##### TL;DR

Without data to work with, here's my guess:

```kotlin
val extractedNames: Map<Long, String?> = destinationDepartment
  .mapValues { (_, userData: Map<String, Any?>) ->
    when (val name = userData["name"]) {
      is String -> name
      else      -> null
    }
  }
println(extractedNames)
// {1=Bergen, 2=Cindy, 3=Dave}
```

##### Intro

Kotlin is great for manipulating collections. For a more general of how to work with collections in Kotlin, I think the docs are really clear [Collection transformation operations#Map](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collection-transformations.html#map).

Let's see how that works for this example. You want to extract a specific element, so for that we can use [`map()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map.html).

From your screenshot it looks like this is a `Map<Long, Map>`, where the value is a `Map<String, Any?>`. I'll assume you want to change the `Map<Long, Map>` to a `Map<Long, String>`, where the key is the database ID and the value is user's name.

##### Test data

So I've got something to test with, I made a new `Map`:

```kotlin
val destinationDepartment: Map<Long, Map<String, Any?>> =
  mapOf(
    1L to mapOf(
      "id" to 1,
      "name" to "Bergen",
      "createdAt" to LocalDateTime.now(),
      "updatedAt" to LocalDateTime.now(),
    ),
    2L to mapOf(
      "id" to 2,
      "name" to "Cindy",
      "createdAt" to LocalDateTime.now(),
      "updatedAt" to LocalDateTime.now(),
    ),
    3L to mapOf(
      "id" to 3,
      "name" to "Dave",
      "createdAt" to LocalDateTime.now(),
      "updatedAt" to LocalDateTime.now(),
    ),
  )
```

##### Basic noop

First, set up the basics. A [`Map`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/) can be converted to a list of [`Entries`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/-entry/). When we call `map()`, it will iterates over each `Entry`, and applies a lambda - which is something we must write. In this instance, the lambda receives the key and value of the `Map`, and *must* return a new value.

> Aside: the Java equivalent is `map.entrySet().stream().map(...)...`

Here, the lambda just returns a pair (created with [`to`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/to.html)).

```kotlin
val extractedNames = destinationDepartment
  .map { (id: Long, userData: Map<String, Any?>) ->
    id to userData
  }
println(extractedNames)
// Output: [(1, {id=1, name=Bergen, createdAt=2021-08-19T11:00:07.447660, updatedAt=2021-08-19T11:00:07.449969}), 
// (2, {id=2, name=Cindy, createdAt=2021-08-19T11:00:07.463813, updatedAt=2021-08-19T11:00:07.463845}), 
// (3, {id=3, name=Dave, createdAt=2021-08-19T11:00:07.463875, updatedAt=2021-08-19T11:00:07.463890})]
```

Pretty boring! But now we're set up for the next step - extracting name from `userData: Map<String, Any?>`.

##### Extracting name

```kotlin
val extractedNames = destinationDepartment
  .map { (id: Long, userData: Map<String, Any?>) ->
    val name = userData["name"]
    id to name
  }
println(extractedNames)
// Output: [(1, Bergen), (2, Cindy), (3, Dave)]
```

Now there's loads of ways to improve this. Making sure that `name` is a String, not `Any?`, filtering out blank or null names, mapping to DTOs, sorting. Again, the Kotlin documentation would be a good start. I'll start by listing one really good improvement.

##### Converting `List<Pair<>>` to `Map<>`

If you look at the type of `val extractedNames`, you'll see that it's a list, not a map.

```
val extractedNames: List<Pair<Long, Any?>> = ...
```

That's because the lambda we wrote in the `map()` function is returning a `Pair<Long, String>`. Kotlin doesn't know that this is still considered a `Map`. We can convert any `List<Pair<>>` back to a map with [`toMap()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-map.html)

##### `toMap()`

```
val extractedNames: Map<Long, Any?> = destinationDepartment
  .map { (id: Long, userData: Map<String, Any?>) ->
    val name = userData["name"]
    id to name
  }
  .toMap() // convert List<Pair<>> to a Map<>
println(extractedNames)
// Output: {1=Bergen, 2=Cindy, 3=Dave}
```

But this is also not great. Why is `id: Long` in the lambda if we're not using it? Because we're only extracting the `name` from `userData`, we're only mapping the *values* of the `Map`. We don't need `id: Long` at all. Fortunately Kotlin has another useful method: [`mapValues()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-values.html) - and it returns a `Map<>`, so we can drop the `toMap()`. Let's use it.

##### `mapValues()`

```
val extractedNames: Map<Long, Any?> = destinationDepartment
  .mapValues { (id: Long, userData: Map<String, Any?>) ->
    val name = userData["name"]
    id to name
  }
println(extractedNames)
// {1=(1, Bergen), 2=(2, Cindy), 3=(3, Dave)}
```

Umm weird. Why are the `id`s in the values? That's because the `mapValues()` lambda should return the new value, and in our lambda we're returning both the `id` **and** `name` - oops! Let's only return the name.

##### Fixing `mapValues()`

```
val extractedNames: Map<Long, Any?> = destinationDepartment
  .mapValues { (_, userData: Map<String, Any?>) ->
    userData["name"]
  }
println(extractedNames)
// {1=(1, Bergen), 2=(2, Cindy), 3=(3, Dave)}
```

Better! Because `id` is not used, [an underscore can be used instead](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#underscore-for-unused-variables)

> Aside: Note that the lambda doesn't have a `return`. Read [Returning a value from a lambda expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#returning-a-value-from-a-lambda-expression) for an explanation.